# Images in table always higher than text

Tags: html, css

Why are images in cells of a table always higher and don't have any default padding, on the other hand text is always slightly below by default even with no margins or paddings?

Imagine two columns:

```
|     | img |
| txt |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
```

Text is always slightly below with same marging/padding than image... How do I solve this so that both are completely the same? Lets assume image has v-align: top, I want the text and picture vertically aligned (look at teh red line of the picture):

[CLICK ME](http://shrani.si/f/V/e3/4ifEm4jF/untitled.png)

Comment: Tables are designed for tabular data and not for formatting page content.

Comment: As sad as it is I need the table to format the page as I am making templates for an online messaging service that sends mails to a wide range of customers. A lot of them still have older outlook clients which ignore divs

Comment: what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jsCHb Did not work?

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS rule to the image

```
img {

vertical-align:middle;

}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
td {

vertical-align:top;

}
```

This should work:

> **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bDoms**

Comment: Lets assume image has v-align: top, I don't want to change that. That doesn't solve the problem it just centers my image

Comment: Then align the text to top.

Comment: I tried that, you can't align text in cells by verticall pos, you can only align images

Comment: Can't you use `valign` on text?

Comment: Why do you want the image to be top aligned? What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is another way to do this. Add some more information to your question. (Images, code, etc,...).

Comment: I use `style="vertical-align: top;"` in `<td>` element of a `table`, doesn't do nothing...

Comment: for some reason vertical-align:top; doesn't do nothing, NOTHING

Answer (score 0):

better to add some style like this  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jsCHb)

**HTML**

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">text</th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAFoAmAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAADAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwQCBQEGB//EAEAQAAEDAgEGCgcGBgMAAAAAAAEAAgMREgQFITFRkdETFUFSYXFykpOxFCI0NVSy0iMyM4GhwkNic3TB8EJEgv/EABgBAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAMC/8QAIREAAgEDBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAECERJRAwQTMTIhM0H/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AP2GaWV08jGSljWECjQM+YHlHSs3z6PSZNjdy8d7Vie2PlapsRgIp5uFMkzHUoeDdbVSTnJSf01SVCq6f4mTY3ci6f4mTY3cpX4Fj3hzpZuTNfmzU6OjzS+LIs/2+J6KSUp/tFzfLI6LBddP8TJsbuRdP8TJsbuS4ImwRCNrnuA5XmpKYi+WR2oLp/iZNjdyXiX4sYeUwYk8KGEsvDba0zVzaFqQuawljbncja0qp3TYmlPRa9UoRfLI1BFDHYmwX4l91M9GtpXYtXT/ABMmxu5TPmxIeQzDVbWgN42p8ZcY2l7Q1xAqByFF8sg4I1dP8TJsbuRdP8TJsbuQkPlnDjZh7hXTeAi+WRKCZqKXGGaZr5XNY0ixwtq7NnrmzZ026f4mTY3cpeGxFlwwhLyc4vGrX1p0D5Hh3CxcHQ5vWrVF8snTgu6DLp/iZNjdyLp/iZNjdyEI5JZObUF0/wATJsbuRdP8TJsbuQhF8shajLMVLFjsPC+QyNmuHrAVBAB5AvEiT3vk/rk8ghU6bbj9MpKjGSz25Rmi4KQ3Gt7W1aKNbmJ1plw1O2L13tWJ7Y+Vqw+eNji1xNRpo0lTzTcnQ1TSijV41O2LM07Ibb7vW1Cqz6VFrd3HbkelRa39x25c2ywF0cmG46BzHPBda0VJtK1Di4pn2MJJz8mpe+lRa3dx25BxcQFSXdw7kWywO+AwupyO2Iv6HbF61zXtDmkFpFQRypXpMPOJ6Qwn/CSTfQNpDLuh3dKLuh2wpfpUOt3cduR6VFrd3Hbk7ZYFdHIy7od3SvbtYd3SlelRa3dx25HpUOariM9KlpARbLAXRNNeLn5naR/xOoLV41O7pXlwZwjnGgB0/kFj0qLW7uO3JJN9DbSGXjU7ulF41O7pS/Sotbu47cj0qLW7uO3J2ywK6ORl41O7pReP5u6Uo4qEaS7uHctMxET3hodRx0Agiu1FrwOqJhMybLODay6sb5GuuYRntGiulCZJ73yd1yeQQqtLyZT7KXe1Yntj5WqaLTJ23eapd7Vie2Plapov4nbd5p7f9WZ63hCI3Y4S0kjiMd33gc9OpZY/KFfWihprrpViFdQkqCEITES5DJOQ8KSc/AjyToq+jsppsFK9SRkL3Fhf6Q8k3DSxuhaGvaSxoDgDoNNBUO07kV7hfEJifj6FskcRzGjg7lpm/VahfjS4cNHCG1z0Oc7lQZI2mjntB6SvOFjoTe2gNNKtJqPBtRZYzZNnpqHmFW17Hfde0000OhQ5ZljGAljMjL3NBDbhUioXM/LHFO5F05+wJ/nZ5tXkt/BO4Kl9PVroqif8A9tn7VtTbPyzbc+kSNfjzG6+KJr6C0h1QTXPX8v9C3h3Ytzhw8cTG9BqetUE0FToWb284bVWT/TM8TJQwSNra8OGcihHKp8cSMTk/P8A9j9jlS5zagXNqDylTY/2nJ/9z+xyy1vzZpp1uiUye98n9cnkhEnvfJ/XJ5IUul5Kp9lLvasT2x8rVNF/E7bvNUu9qxPbHytU0X8Ttu809v8AqzjW8I2hCFeRghCEhkmQvcWG/ojyTsNGxsDLWNFzQTQUqaJWQ/cWF/pDyT4PwIuwPJRbTuRVuOkD4o3/AH2ArIw8IbaIxTNm6k1Ct+E10l/TDIY4ySxgBOlSZZY3i6Z1rbgAAaZwKhXKLLPuyfqHmFzPyxxbckVT/gHts82raxP+B/7Z5tW1Ns/LNtz6Rl7Gvba4VBSjhICQeDGbpKehV/DBSa6ZPJhYHOqYwS52fOc/LrSsd7Rk/wDuP2OVM0jYzEHXeu8NFGk5/wAlPj/acn/3H7HLLW/NmkG3KNSmT3vk/rk8kIk975P65PJCl0vJTPspd7Vie2PlapcRk7DYh98jDcdJa4iuxMcMRxliiHRcB6tAWm660V5dFKL2U4gH7JrHCnLmNdqnnVSdDWKqkS8TYPmSeK7ejibB8yTxXb0+/F8GTwcd5pQVrT9epbidiC/7VjGsz6NPRyrm6WR2Il4mwfMk8V29HE2COYxvI5QZHEH9V0EIulkVEZjY2NgYwBrWigA5FHJknBvcXGNwJ5ryB+itfcGm0VdTMFM5+LAJ4KPbo/X/AHySbXR1bUTxNg+ZJ4rt6OJsHzJPFdvT3vxdTZHHbyGun9VQ2tou+9TOndLInFIg4mwfMk8V29esyRgmuDuCJINRc8nP+avQlc8iohZY2RsjHgFrjQgjoCkOR8GTWx/iO3q1ul/a/wABaQm10NpHP4mwfMk8V29HE2D5kniu3roJMzsQHfYsY5tOXTVO6WQUUyXibBcx/iO3puHyZhMPIJY4/XAoHOcSR1VW78XYPs4y6ufPoC3EZy08KGNdXNQVzbUVeQtSFSe98n9cnkhKcJ+PsDc6IwWvto0h11M9c+hCq0vJlPsoxmJjwmKm4cPAeQ5pbG5wIoByA6knjXB86XwH7l3gARnCLRqCT0U3UFNo4PG2D50vgP8ApRxtg+dL4D/pXetGoItGoJcEQvZweNsHzpfAf9KONsHzpfAf9K71o1BFo1BHBEL2cHjbB86XwH/Slz5XwzYJHMEz3BpIY2F4LjTQMy+itGoLygroCOCIXs4EeV8K6NjncMwloJaYX1HRoWuNcHzpfAfuXeAGoItGoI4Ihezg8bYPnS+A/wClHGuD50vgP3LvWjUEWjUEcEQvZ85DlaHhJuFLg2/7O2GQ1bQac2bPXYm8bYPnS+A/6V3qDUEWjUEcER8jZweNsHzpfAf9KONcHzpfAfuXetGoItGoI4IivZweNcHzpfAfuRxrg+dL4D9y71o1BFo1BHBEL2cDDzMxuVcG7DiRzYry9xjc0CoAGkBC79ADmCFpGKiqI5bqf//Z" alt="" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">text 2</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; }
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;/*padding:10px 5px;*/border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal; vertical-align:top;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;/*padding:10px 5px;*/border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal; vertical-align: top;height: 200px;}
img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
td {
  vertical-align:top;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: for some reason `vertical-align:top;` doesn't do nothing, NOTHING

Comment: then you have something wrong is written can lead you to a bunch of examples that this method works

Comment: Not for me, I have padding of 20px on both cells, picture and text, both have valign top and my text is in <p> and <h1> tags

Comment: if you look closely at the code you will see the indentation commented uncomment and you will Happiness